# GitHub repository created but unable to upload VS solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github

I tried uploading a C++ project from Visual Studio 2019 onto my GitHub account.

The repository gets created when I do this however, none of my codes gets uploaded onto the repository.

Only the files ".gitattributes" and ".gitignore" appear in my repository.

Please could I have any suggestions on what I could do to fix this.

[image: Here's how my team explorer looks]

Comment: Did you stage your files?
Visual Studio >> Team Explorer >> Changes will show the list of newly-created and/or updated files.  You need to click the "+" sign to stage them.  When you commit, they will get pushed to your repo.

Comment: what commands where you executing to push your code?

Comment: Hi @BillJetzer, thanks for your reponse. I've just tried what you recommended however when I click the "+" sign in Changes, it doesn't give me an option to stage them.

Comment: try to do this in line command. 

in the folder of project type: git add . 

git commit -m "my first commit"
git push

Comment: Hi @Paulo, I'm new to GitHub and these repositories, so I'm not quite sure about where to enter these commands.

Comment: Well. you can type this commands on "package manager console" of visual studio. if you can't see, look in View menu.
then tryed type the command i sayed above.

Comment: @Paulo, I tried copying and pasting the commands you gave me in the package manager console and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It says "git: error: unknown switch 'm' "

Comment: tryed to type all the commands separately. First: git add . (dont forget the "." )

Comment: second: git commit -m "message"

Comment: third: git push

Comment: thanks @Paulo, it's stored the files on the repository

Comment: Fyi-in the screenshot you added, the files are staged. All that is required after that is to add a comment and then commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close VS
Go to your local repository folder (the solution folder)

This will add all the files and commit them

```
git add .
git commit -m 'added files'
```

alternatively you can use "git add ___" to add one file at a time

Make sure you commit the changes and then do

"git push"

Re-open VS and everything should be setup now.

Here are some other instructions I wrote down recently which you may find helpful:

**How to create a git repo from an ungitted local project already in development:**

Create a empty repo on your repo hosting site

Go to your local project folder in git command line

git init

git add .

git commit -m 'message'

git remote add origin https://yourreposite.com/username/repo

git push -u origin master

Now you can open it in Visual Studio and everything is all setup